# Javascript won't run on UIWebView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I am trying to run javascript on UIWebView and so far everything has been great, but I got a problem where I need to change a value in selection box, I am doing this `document.getElementById('dt').selectedIndex = 5;` somehow UIWebView won't change it, I can read the value perfectly, but somehow it doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to parse the HTML of the page, and change the selected value. Because the HTML is available for you when a page is loaded, it shouldn't be hard to do a replace or whatever.

If you want to use javascript, check [this](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview) link

Comment: I am doing this now:
NSString * scriptString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"document.getElementById('dt').selectedIndex = 5;"];
NSString *ret = [hiddenView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:scriptString];

This should work perfectly...